# How do I make the y axis of this graph start at zero?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")    

'''Since there are no unary operators supported between 'counter' and the variable 'i',
I must declare another variable 'counter' and set it equal to zero, with the value
of counter being updated by 1 each time.'''
total_cases = []
counter = 0;
global_case_information = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"maincounter-number"})
for cases in global_case_information:
    if(counter == 13):
        break
    else:
        total_cases.append(cases.text)
        counter += 1    
global_cases = {"Total Deaths":total_cases[1], "Total Recovered":total_cases[2]}

covid_figure = plt.figure()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [40, 40]
keys_array = np.arange(len(global_cases.keys()))

axes = plt.gca()
plt.xticks(keys_array, global_cases.keys())
plt.ylabel("Number Of People Affected(Globally)")
plt.title("Global Covid-19 Statistics")    
plt.bar(keys_array, global_cases.values())    
plt.show()
```

Alright, so I am trying to make the y-axis start at zero, and have a relative offset of 50000 units. However, that's not what's going on, and I even tried doing the following:

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 300000, 50000))

But that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the following command just before plt.show()

```
plt.set_ylim(ymin=0)
```

I hope you're asking about this. Please let me know.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't do anything. The smallest value is still the y-value of the bar with the smallest value.

Comment: Oh..Then please share me your full py code and let me play with that.

Comment: That was pretty much it, at the top I did the following:                                                                import bs4 import BeautifulSoup, import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, import requests, from matplotlib.figure import Figure, from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk, import numpy as np, import matplotlib.